# I can not fix the errors in Spring project using kotlin. Please show me reason for these errors

Tags: gradle, kotlin

I am a basic developer with kotlin.
I tried to download this project and build it in order to study more about kotlin.
But this project has some errors.
This is a Spring project using kotlin.
Now it could not find and import some modules.
So it has not built and has these [errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbcWN.png)

But I have one issue.
The `map`module does not exist in this project really.
What is this situation and how can I build this successfully?
[module path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qa5Qo.png)

Comment: Unfortunately it's not possible to help you without having more information. If this project is available for public download, please post a link to where you downloaded it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About the errors photo you attached, it seems you have 2 kotlin versions installed (1.2.71 & 1.3.10).
I suggest to remove one of them (probably the old one) and try to build again.

About the `map` module - I don't know what is this project - how you import it, which version it has, etc..

Comment: I admire your issue. And I removed conflicted kotlin version1.2.71 with your opinion. So I fitted kotlin conflicted warnning. But this was not real reason for my issue.  This was detected not to export gradle module. I fitted my errors with terminal command" ./gradle build". Thanks a lot.

Comment: ok, can you share how you imported the problematic module with not exists `map`?. or even share the whole gradle?

Answer (score 0):

Oh I forgot set environment value. It is solved when I run after set environment value as 'source shell/env.proto.sh'. Thanks a lot. But I can fix kotlin conflic error to remove ko